# Is a first differenced Markov process still Markovian?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, markov-process, random-walk

If a discrete random variable forms a Markov process, then you obtain 
the time series from it.

If you first difference that time series (i.e. Markov process). Do you still get the Markov property or would each value be independent of all the other values?

Comment: It is not Markov and the observations would not be independent.

Comment: So does that mean that the observations are dependent, but wouldn't be in the form of $\ Pr(X_t | X_(t-1) , X_(t-2) , X_(t-3) ...) = Pr(X_t | X_(t-1) $ ?

Comment: You should clean up your subscripting. But it looks like the definition of the Markov property.  It is not Markov so it does not satisfy the Markov property.

Comment: i'm not sure how i can edit my comment. But if the dependency isn't markov, is there any specific ways those observations are dependent? or is it case by case?